# Linq to entities parametrized constructor Datetime

Tags: linq, datetime, entities

i know that Linq to entities does not support parametrized constructors, but how to do this pls ?:

```
date = new DateTime(int.Parse(SqlFunctions.StringConvert(l.rok).Trim()), int.Parse(SqlFunctions.StringConvert(l.mesic).Trim()), 1)
```

Whole example:

```
var objects = from object in GetObjects()
                   select new MyObject{
                   name = object.name;
                   date = new DateTime(object.rok,object.month,object.day)
                   }
```

How to do this?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Use the EntityFunctions CreateDateTime method found here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.objects.entityfunctions.createdatetime

These helper methods were built to translate to a SQL equivalent, as noted in the remarks of that link:

> You cannot call this function directly. This function can only appear
>   within a LINQ to Entities query.
>
> This function is translated to a corresponding function in the
>   database.

Comment: This is now replaced by System.Data.Entity.DbFunctions.CreateDateTime

Comment: A mini example with "CreateDateTime" would be nice. Thanks